# Inner Elements Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I've set up a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/1/ with the following markup -

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="clickable">item 1
        <ul>
            <li>subitem 1</li>
            <li>subitem 2</li>
            <li>subitem 3</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li class="clickable">item 3
        <ul>
            <li>subitem 1</li>
            <li>subitem 2</li>
            <li>subitem 3</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I use the following code -

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

where only the elements with class clickable can be clicked.

When I click one of the sublist's item, the whole li slides up. I only want it to happen when the parent element is clicked and not one of the children(s). How can I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: Or you could also add `return false;` instead of `stopPropagation()` to avoid event bubbeling.

Comment: @AWolf, stopPropagation doesn't work in my case. Don't know why. Try it with the fiddle

Comment: other alternative [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course `stopPropagation` doesn’t work with your current code – because you are only handling the click event occuring on your `.clickable` elements, but that is not the event that you want to stop from bubbling up; that would be the click event that occurs on the inner list items, but since you don’t handle that event, you can not stop it from bubbling either.

You should rather check the *target* of the click event in your code – for example, if it has the class `clickable`:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('clickable')) {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation` to stop event bubbling.

http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/2/

```
$('.list li').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

**According to comment from OP:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/4/
You can also be more specific while binding the click to the element, so you are free to bind another event on the parent for list slideup and down

```
$('.list ul li').on('click', function(event){

    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I had already tried that but forgot to update the question. Please see updated question

Comment: @NaeemShaikh: no problem. I can't/didn't see it update

Comment: @NaeemShaikh please see this http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/1/ to be more specific. I want the slideToggle to work with the only the elements which can be clicked i.e. li.clickable

Comment: @NaeemShaikh, clicking the list subitem shouldn't slideUp, it's undesirable. Only the li.clickable when clicked should slideUp/slideDown

Answer (score 0):

Try this [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqegh7yz/3/)

Comment: Sorry, I had already tried event.stopPropagation() but didn't work in my case  please see the updated question.

Comment: Ohhhh @SnorkS I misunderstood problem :(